# Backtrack maze-game how to put a timer?

Tags: java, backtracking, maze

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class Backtrack
{
    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel panel;

    private JTable table;

    public Backtrack()

    {
        table = new JTable(5, 5){

            DefaultTableCellRenderer render = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

            {
                render.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            }

            @Override
            public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int arg0, int arg1)
            {
                return render;
            }

        };
        table.setRowHeight(55);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        table.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 32));
        table.setValueAt("X", 1, 0);
        table.setValueAt("X", 1, 2);
        table.setValueAt("X", 1, 3);
        table.setValueAt("X", 3, 1);
        table.setValueAt("X", 4, 0);
        table.setValueAt("X", 4, 2);
        table.setValueAt("X", 2, 3);
        table.setValueAt("X", 3, 4);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 350));
        panel.add(table);

        frame = new JFrame("Backtracking Algorithm");
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(500, 300);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        solve(0, 0, 5);
    }

    public boolean solve(int row, int col, int n)
    {
        table.setValueAt("O", row, col);

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}

        if (row == n - 1 && col == n - 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        //table.setValueAt("", row, col);

        if (validMove(row, col - 1, n))
        {
            if (solve(row, col - 1, n))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (validMove(row - 1, col, n))
        {
            if (solve(row - 1, col, n))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (validMove(row, col + 1, n))
        {
            if (solve(row, col + 1, n))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (validMove(row + 1, col, n))
        {
            if (solve(row + 1, col, n))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        table.setValueAt("", row, col);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean validMove(int row, int col, int n)
    {
        if (row > n - 1 || col > n - 1 || row < 0 || col < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (table.getValueAt(row, col) != null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Backtrack backtrack = new Backtrack();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will appreciate your help T_T

Comment: consider giving some description of your problem....instead of just code

Comment: My maze needs an timer and a score where in after it reach its destination it will automatically get 100 pts

Answer (score 0):

For a timer you could implement

> [org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html)

or

> [Java.lang.System.nanoTime()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_nanotime.htm)

For the score you could simply declare a variable and increment it whenever your `solve()` returns `true`